# export tables as xls sheet in ReactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have multiple tables in my page and I want to export tables as a **single xls sheet**.

```
 <div>{store.ratecardList.map(ratecard => {
    return(
      <div key={ratecard.ratecardId} className="box-filter">
        <table id={ratecard.ratecardId} width="100%" border="0" 
  cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" className="box-filter-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input className="ratecard_checkbox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value={ratecard.ratecardId}/></td>
              <td>Rate Card Name<br/>
                <strong>{ratecard.rateCardName}</strong></td>
              <td align="center"> Created by<br/>
                <strong> {ratecard.createdByFullName}</strong></td>
              <td align="center"> Date Modifield<br/>
                <strong> {ratecard.dateModified} </strong></td>
              <td align="center"> Date Created<br/>
                <strong>{ratecard.dateCreated}</strong></td>
              <td>
                <div className="box-filter-view-more"><Link to={`/ratecard/${ratecard.ratecardId}`} className="btn btn-primary pull-right button-grey">VIEW</Link></div> </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>  
        </table>
      </div>
      );
     })}
```

Users can select tables by checkboxes and I have ratecardId of selected checkboxes in an array named checkedValues.

jQuery answers are accepted.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this library ?
https://github.com/clarketm/TableExportr

you could simply generate your xsl file just with code like this:

```js
new TableExport(document.getElementsByTagName(rateCard.rateId));
```

Comment: we cannot export multiple tables in a single file with this library.
thanks for the reply btw.